# Get a value of a row when another value in that row is maximal with conditions

Tags: python, apply

How can I get the 'Name' value of a row that has maximal of absolute 'Score' for each pair of 'Gender' and 'Group'?
I have a dataframe as below:

```
df
Out[6]: 
   Name  Gender Group  Score
0  Time    Male     B      8
1  John    Male     A      6
2   May    Male     B    -10
3  Lily  Female     A      4
4   Ahn  Female     A      3
```

For each pair of 'Gender' and ' Group', I'd like to get the 'Name' with the highest absolute score.
For eg, it's "May" for pair "Male"-"B", "John" for pair "Male"-"A".
The resulted dataframe should look like this:

```
   Gender   Group      NameOfHighest    MaxAbs
0    Male     B               May       10
1    Male     A              John        6
2  Female     A              Lily        4
```

I'm doing the code below but it does not work properly. It gives `nan` error.

```
df_final = df[['Gender','Group']].drop_duplicates()
df_final['NameOfHighest'] = ''
df_final['NameOfHighest'] = df_final.apply(lambda row:df['Name'][df['Score'] == abs(df['Score'][(df['Gender']==row['Gender'])&(df['Group']==row['Group'])]).max()], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
df['MaxAbs'] = df['Score'].abs()
idx = df.groupby(['Gender', 'Group'])['MaxAbs'].transform(max) == df['MaxAbs']
grouped_data = df[idx]
print(grouped_data)
```

output:

```
   Name  Gender Group  Score  MaxAbs
1  John    Male     A      6       6
2   May    Male     B    -10      10
3  Lily  Female     A      4       4
```

Comment: You can also use [idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for slightly more straightforward code